# sed with a generated string as command

Tags: bash, sed

I have an xml that contains paths to 3 other xml files. Let's call the files main, cfg, config and engine. Relavant extract from main.xml:

```
<cfgfile>path/to/cfg/cfg.xml</cfgfile>
<enginefile>path/to/engine/engine.xml</enginefile>
<configfile>path/to/config/config.xml</configfile>
```

I want to replace "path/to/x" with pwd (and copy main, cfg, config and engine to pwd). For cfg alone I could do this:

`sed 's%path/to/cfg/cfg.xml%"$(pwd)"/cfg.xml' source_path/main.xml > ./main.xml`

To make it "simpler" I am trying to this through a loop:

```
S="";
for ele in "cfg" "engine" "config"; do
S=$S's%<'"$ele"'>.*</'"$ele"'>%<'"$ele"'>'"$(pwd)"'</'"$ele"'>;';
done;
echo $S
```

I have similar changes in the other 3 files. So, instead of typing out all the commands, loops would be better. I know I could use awk or python more easily, but just trying it out with sed.
So the question is can I use generated variable S as a command in a sed oneliner (without redirecting it to a file) Something like:   `sed 'use $S' source_path/a.xml`

Comment: If the words `XML` and `sed` appear in a question, then something is basically wrong. [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: @Cyrus Agree with that. But the application for which I am doing this could as well have accepted command line arguments. There are no nested tags. It's more of a "tag: val" file which is why I thought an abomination might not be so ugly (here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible to execute dynamically constructed `sed` program with

```
sed -e "$S" input-file.txt > output-file.txt
```

Note that the loop suggested to generate the script has few typos - it will return:

```
s%<cfg>.*</cfg>%<cfg>PWD</cfg>;
s%<engine>.*</engine>%<engine>PWD</engine>;
s%<config>.*</config>%<config>PWD</config>;
```

Missing trailing '%', misspelling the tag name, not include the filename, etc. The code to generate the string should be fixed (and simplified) to:

```
s=""
for ele in "cfg" "engine" "config"; do
    tag=${ele}file
    s="${s}s%<$tag>.*</$tag>%<$tag>$(pwd)/$ele.xml</$tag>%;"
done;
#
sed -e "$s" ...
```

Comment: This will only work in this special case. As soon as the XML-entity has an XML-attribute, a subentity, a space or many other things possible in XML, it will fail.

Comment: While I do agree with Marco and @Cyrus, I think I'll accept this answer because of the specific use case that I find myself in, and I was actually looking for the "sed -e" usage - somehow I managed to bungle in using it, and had to come here.

Comment: Fixed a typo - missing trailing '%' in the 's' command (and improve identification)

Answer (score 2):

@Cyrus comment is absolutely right. XML is more than you might think.

And if you know XPath you can easily use `xmlstarlet` together with `sed`.

```
for a in cfgfile enginefile configfile
do
    temppath="$( xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//${a}" -v "normalize-space(node())"  main.xml | sed -e "s#path/to/[^\/]\+#$( pwd )#g" )"
    tempxml="$( xmlstarlet ed -u "//${a}" -v "${temppath}" main.xml )" && echo "${tempxml}" > main.xml
done
```

This makes sure you do not break the XML Structure.
Unfortunately there is no regex-match-replace function in XPath (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you  (GNU sed):

```
sed -En 's#(.*)path/to(.*)#echo "\1$(pwd)\2"#ep' file
```

Turn off implicit printing and extend regexps (`-n` and `-E`).

Substitute `path/to` for the `pwd` command which will be interpolated by `echo` in the string `\1$(pwd)\2` where `\1` and `\2` are the parts of the line before and after `path/to`. The RHS of the substitution command is evaluated due to the `e` flag and then printed with the flag `p`.